# Increase Height of ion.RangeSlider?

Tags: jquery, html, css, slider, range

I am currently using ion.RangeSlider for my project which can be found here:

http://ionden.com/a/plugins/ion.rangeSlider/en.html

It works great but I'm wondering if anyone knows how to increase the size/height of the slider? I've tried height & padding with no avail. I can decrease the height but it seems to cap out at a certain height.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can u share a fiddle mate?

Answer (score 3):

The Ion.RangeSlider is using an image as background, therefore, it isn't possible to simply use `height` on CSS. But you can use:

```
.irs-bar, .irs-line,.irs-slider{
        transform: scaleY(1.2);
}
```

To increase the slider bar/line. And to increase the whole component:

```
.irs{
    transform: scaleY(1.2);
}
```

Note that `scaleY` is a percentual increase.